# #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation '='

Tags: mysql, double-byte

This error is occurred while selecting with date field.The date field  type is "date" and the searched value is double byte.The searched condition is `birth_day` =  '１９９４０４０３'.
How can we avoid the mysql error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [convert string to date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: in the case of double byte string str to date will work?

Comment: First, try it. Double-byte is ucs2 character set. It means it is string.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time